# How to show primefaces icon error programatically?

Tags: primefaces

i have input field and message icon component as follows:

```
    <h:form id="myForm" >
     <p:inputText id="email"  />  
     <p:message id="iconMessage" for="email" display="icon" />
```

and i have a submit button that checks in server side for email existence in database, and if it exists i want to make the error icon appears as follows:

```
FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage("myForm:email",
                    new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR, "", ""));
```

but the error icon won't render, please advise how to fix that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to update the component:

```
RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().update("myForm:email");
```

from

```
org.primefaces.context.RequestContext;
```

But I would advise specifying a validator instead:

```
<p:inputText id="email" validator="{yourBean.validateEmail}" />
```

and in your managed bean:

```
public void validateEmail(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, Object value) {
    String email = value.toString();

    //check if email exists in DB

    FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(component.getClientId(context),
                new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR, "", ""));
    }
}
```